# Using a ListViewBuilder with a row in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving data from a database that works but I have an issue where the data is not being displayed in a CustomWidget card I've created. I've tried using shrinkwrap, expanded, and flexible but none work. I'm assuming it might be my placement but I'm not so sure.
I'm getting these errors:

*'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1869 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true.

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#39186 relayoutBoundary=up36 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':

Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'*

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getListing(),
          builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data.length);
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                  return Row(children:  <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: ItemsCard(
                      image: defaulturl+"${snapshot.data[index].image}", // var defaulturl = "https://sam-thige.000webhostapp.com/productimages/";
                      title: "${snapshot.data[index].description}",
                      location: "${snapshot.data[index].location}",
                    ),
                  ),
            ]);
                }
              );
            }
            else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the ItemsCard widget

```
class ItemsCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemsCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.location,
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String image, title, location;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 50.0),
        width: size.width * 0.4,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(image),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(251, 105, 111, 216),
                          blurRadius: 20.0,
                          offset: Offset(0, 10))
                    ]),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "$title \n",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "$location",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)))
                        ]))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: what behavior is happening with the gesturedetector

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not giving us the full code of your custom widget named **ItemsCard**, it's kinda hard to tell if the Row -> Flexible widget parents are necessary. Skipping that, your **ListView.builder** it's not horizontal, but vertical, so it doesn't have any space to render horizontally. The solution for this is to add width to your **SizedBox** like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width //adding the whole screen's width,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getListing(),
        builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data.length);
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                return Row(children:  <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: ItemsCard(
                    image: defaulturl+"${snapshot.data[index].image}", // var defaulturl = "https://sam-thige.000webhostapp.com/productimages/";
                    title: "${snapshot.data[index].description}",
                    location: "${snapshot.data[index].location}",
                  ),
                ),
                ]);
              }
            );
          }
          else{
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        }
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I added the item card widget

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a fixed height and width for your `listView.Builder`.
You can use it as a parent of `FutureBulder` or as a parent of `listView.builder`. You can change the height or width as your requirement. It is just the solution.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getListing(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return SizedBox(
              height: size.height,
              width: size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Row(children: const <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: ItemsCard(
                          image: defaulturl +
                              "${snapshot.data[index].image}", // var
                          // defaulturl = "https://sam-thige.000webhostapp.com/productimages/";
                          title: "${snapshot.data[index].description}",
                          location: "${snapshot.data[index].location}",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]);
                  }));
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
           );
         }
       }
     ),
  );
}
```